# os.mkdir's rights assigning doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, unix

I'm trying to create directory with 777 rights.

```
os.mkdir(Xmldocument.directory, 0777)
```

However what I get is 775

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 mwysoki mwysoki 4096 Nov  9 11:38 VeloDBBrowser
```

I'm sure that I have appropriate rights because chmod 777 works just fine.

Comment: When I try it (as root), I get permissions 755.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current umask is applied here as well.

Normally, files are created with `0777` (if executable or directory) or `0666` (other files.)

Then the OS applies the current umask to this value, resulting into `0755` resp. `0644` seen on most files, as the most usual umask is `0022`.

Your solution would be to set the umask to `0`.